# ¿A qué acepción de "pegar" se refiere "pegarse una siesta"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado

Le comentaba hoy a mi mujer que mi hijo "se ha pegado una siesta de hora y media". Del mismo modo, puedo decirle que "me he pegado una caminata de seis kilómetros". Este uso pronominal de ***[pegar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SKdzxQw)***, ¿a qué acepción corresponde?

Opciones posibles según veo:

- Acepción 7: junto con algunos nombres, para expresar la acción que estos significan. Así, "pegarse una siesta" sería "sestear", aunque no sé qué verbo correspondería con "pegarse una caminata".
- Acepción 13: realizar una acción con decisión y esfuerzo. No hay que hacer mucho esfuerzo para dormir la siesta, pero podría ser. Lo malo es que esta acepción no está marcada como pronominal.
- Acepción desconocida: es un uso regional que no está contemplado en el diccionario. No debería, porque además de usarlo yo, que soy de Sevilla, encuentro frases en el CREA correspondientes a *El diario vasco* como "Si quieres vas a Ipurua a ver al Eibar o te pegas una excursión a Pamplona".

¿Qué acepción de "pegar" se podría asociar pues a este uso del verbo?

Comment: A mi el significado que mejor me cuadra sería la acepción 7 pero no es pronominal, así que tampoco nos sirve. En otros diccionarios hay otras acepciones de *pegar* que no están en el DLE pero ninguna para esa expresión.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Consultada a la RAE](https://twitter.com/charliealejo/status/930704011367460865) en Twitter (y viendo que aprovechan el nuevo límite de 280 caracteres), [me responden](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/930729986591547392):

> Sí, cabría en las dos acepciones que menciona. El DEA de M. Seco trae una acepción coloquial transitiva 'dar (hacer o realizar)', indicando que el CD expresa acción o efecto. Los ejemplos son de «pegarse un paseo/una vida» y «pegar voces».

El diccionario al que se refiere es el *Diccionario del español actual* de [Manuel Seco Reymundo](http://www.rae.es/academicos/manuel-seco-reymundo), publicado en 1999 y considerado el último diccionario "[hecho a mano](https://elpais.com/diario/1999/10/05/cultura/939074414_850215.html)". Por tanto, parece que al final las tres opciones que comentaba eran válidas: encaja tanto en la acepción 7 como en la 13 y como en una acepción nueva (que sería la recogida en el DEA).

Comment: Muy interesante lo del diccionario que mencionas.

Comment: Añadiría que la acepción 7 es muy productiva. En rioplatense sirve no sólo para *pegar* sino para *dar*, *echar* y *mandar* (pronominal en todos los casos).